# How do I speed up the load time of my jQuery sticky footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, footer

So I have been looking for a solid solution for a sticky footer for quite sometime. I found one that works well on every page and in every browser; however it takes some time to load and then take effect.  Is there a way I can speed this up?  Maybe load it before the page loads?  Someone mentioned that it could be set to "onDOMready" instead of onLoad?  Does that make sense?

Anyway, here is my code:

```
<script>
function positionFooter() { 
    var mFoo = $("#myfooter"); 
    if ((($(document.body).height() + 
            mFoo.height()) < $(window).height() && 
            mFoo.css("position") == "fixed") || 
            ($(document.body).height() < $(window).height() && 
            mFoo.css("position") != "fixed")) 
    { 
            mFoo.css({ position: "fixed", bottom: "0px" }); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
            mFoo.css({ position: "static" }); 
    } 
} 

    $(document).ready(function () { 
            positionFooter(); 
            $(window).scroll(positionFooter); 
            $(window).resize(positionFooter); 
            $(window).load(positionFooter); 
    });
</script>

<!--content --->

<div id="myfooter" style="width:100%;"><!--footer content--></div>
```

How do I make it load faster?

Comment: You don't need `$(window).load(positionFooter); `

Comment: If you truly want your footer to depend upon the document height (which you code does), then you have to wait for the document to load to know how high it is.

Comment: @Christo I've updated my answer. There was a bug in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No javascript needed (though it is helpful). The best thing to do here is take advantage of the marvelous min-height property rather than calculate from total document height.

html

```
  <div id="wrap">
       <div id="content">
       <footer></footer>
  </div>
```

css

```
  html,body{
      height:100%;
  }
  #wrap{
       min-height:100%;
       position:relative;      
  }

  #content{
       padding-bottom:20px; // allow room for footer
  }
  footer{
       position:absolute;
       width:100%;
       bottom:0;
       left:0;
       height:20px;
  }
```

As your page may be more complex than this, if you are finding that `min-height:100%` in css alone is not yielding the desired result, you may want to set in with javascript.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       var $window = $(window),
           $wrap = $('#wrap'),
           setMinHeight = function(){
                $wrap.css('min-height',$window.height());
           };
           setMinHeight();
           $window.resize(setMinHeight);
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A6fXe/3/)** al la @Nick

**[DEMO with more content](http://jsfiddle.net/w8PRf/1/)**

Comment: This is the best solution as it doesn't rely on JavaScript.

Comment: Actually you have to give `margin-top: -20px;` to `#wrap`. Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qs9vM/), and here is your example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qs9vM/1/)

Comment: @Morpheus You've almost got it but your footer has spacing at the bottom. Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/A6fXe/1/

Comment: And to think I got distracted while editing this, and didn't finish my answer.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Your demos are still messed up. `#wrap` needs to have a top or bottom negative margin the same as the height of the footer. You need to get rid of the padding property.

Comment: @Nick I don't think so, they look right to me. Padding-bottom as the footer height, is just my preference for handling it vs negative margin.

Comment: @Nick after some experimentation, negative margin and padding both dont cover both demos. But I found another solution, answer and demos updated.